symmetric_difference() multiple sets in python
I have three sets and I want to get the symmetric_difference.
primes = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11}
odds = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}
threes =. {1, 3, 6, 9, 12}

Using the regular way
set(primes) ^ set(odds) ^ set(threes)
result a : {2, 3, 6, 12)

HOWEVER I saw the geeks4geeks link whose solution is converting each set into a list, combine them together, and return only the elements that have only one occurrence.
 result b:  {2, 6, 12}

which one should be correct?

The geeks4geeks version gives the same result as yours if you apply it to 2 lists at a time: for example, solve temp = set(primes) ^ set(odds), then temp ^ set(threes).

thank you Scott!   I guess I was confusing this with the other set operators.  The other set operators ( union, intersect, difference)  will always return the same results when you are applying the operation against multiple sets but this symmetric_difference is a different beast altogether.

Geekforgeek's solution is giving the result of elements which are present only in one of the sets strictly. i.e element which are present only in one set and if an element present even in 2 sets, that will be omitted. And the same result can be obtained with ^ and | as well.
r = (primes | odds) ^ (odds | threes)
print(r) # Output : {2, 6, 12}

with the ex-or method(Exclusive-Or gate) for two sets, the resultant-set contains the elements present only in one set, but not in both the sets.
For eg., take the element 1 in the sets. when you do with primes^odds^threes: the first step is obtained_result_from_first_step = primes^odds i.e 1 is present in both the sets. So, 1 is omitted. The second step is obtained_result_from_first_step ^ threes. Now 1 is present in threes, but not in the obtained_result_from_first_step. So in the resultant, 1 is presnt.
So, which method to adapt depends on what type of result you want. If you want to get the sets of elements present only in one set but not in all the sets, Even that can be attained only by using gate-method. i.e without converting into the list. See all the cases below:
primes = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11}
odds = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}
threes = {1, 3, 6, 9, 12}

# yours
r = primes^odds^threes 
print(r) # case 1 Output : {1, 2, 3, 6, 12}

# similar to Geekforgeek but with gate-method    
r = (primes | odds) ^ (odds | threes)
print(r) # case 2 Output : {2, 6, 12}

# geeks4geeks
ex_or = list(primes) + list(odds) + list(threes)
ex_or = [x for x in ex_or if ex_or.count(x)==1]
print(ex_or) # case 3 Output : [2, 6, 12]


There is a difference between symmetric difference of 2 sets and symmetric difference of more than 2 sets.
primes = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11}
odds = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}
threes = {1, 3, 6, 9, 12}

If you do:
set(primes) ^ set(odds) ^ set(threes)

it will calculate:
{2, 9} ^ set(threes)

{2, 9} ^ {1, 3, 6, 9, 12}

Result will be:
{1, 2, 3, 6, 12}

According to G4G:
combined = [*primes,*odds,*threes]

#[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 1, 3, 6, 9, 12]

Finally,
{x for x in combined if combined.count(x)==1}

#{2, 6, 12}



Mathematically, to find the symmetric difference of 3 sets you can simply do:
(primes ^ odds ^ threes) - (primes & odds & threes)

#Output
#{2, 6, 12}

If someone wants to know the mathematics:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174584/applying-the-symmetric-difference-to-multiple-sets

but what would be the correct answer though - it looks like at least for my problem, the correct answer should be:
step 1:    a = prime ^ odds
step 2:   b = a  ^ threes
And as much as I like the G4G solution,  I felt that  [2, 3, 6, 12] might be the correct one.

Correct answer should be :  where all the elements only occur once. if an element is present in 2 or more sets it should not be included in the result set. In your problem 3 is included in 2 sets so it should not be included in the final result. Only elements which are present once in all three sets are {2, 6, 12}

Couldn't you just do {x for x in combined if combined.count(x)%2 == 1}?

hi @FP - should the answer match just (primes ^ odds ^ threes) ?  I do feel that the G4G may have gotten it wrong.

@punsoca the correct answer should be (primes ^ odds ^ threes) - (primes & odds & threes) . We have to subtract the part which is repeated. G4G is correct. There is a difference btw taking the symmetric_difference of 2 sets and more than 2 sets.

Here is another link for symmetric_difference of 4 sets: https://www.javatpoint.com/symmetric-difference-of-multiple-sets-in-python

@ScottHunter Nops. we don't values which are occuring odd number of times. We only want the values which occur once in the combined set.

stated another way, we want: {item for item, count in Counter(chain(primes, odds, threes)).items() if count == 1}

@juanpa.arrivillaga yup you're right brother!
